# "Unavaliable io exception" when connecting to remote Bazel master on bazel-buildfarm

Tags: java, bazel

I want to setup a small POC remote area with 1x master (`192.168.60.99`) and 1x worker (`192.168.60.98`) using [bazel-buildfarm](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm). Both are CentOS 7 machines provisioned with Vagrant. When connection from a Ubuntu workstation (third machine) in the network, the following error occurs:

```
$ bazel build --verbose_failures //projects/myproj:app
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
 Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=229
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/user/tests/ecommerce/.bazelrc:
 'build' options: --strategy=TypeScriptCompile=worker --strategy=AngularTemplateCompile=worker --symlink_prefix=dist/ --define=compile=legacy --incompatible_strict_action_env --experimental_allow_incremental_repository_updates --distdir=third_party/_distdir
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/user/.bazelrc:
 'build' options: --spawn_strategy=remote --genrule_strategy=remote --strategy=Javac=remote --strategy=Closure=remote --remote_executor=192.168.60.99:8980
INFO: Writing tracer profile to '/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/24700f1ad3e201a00a1c26bd59dc6502/command.profile.gz'
INFO: Invocation ID: 569b59ca-edcb-4922-92a0-b6f0b5ca2819
ERROR: Failed to query remote execution capabilities: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

The network connection is working and I even can connect to Bazel using telnet:

```
telnet 192.168.60.99 8980
Trying 192.168.60.99...
Connected to 192.168.60.99.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

`.bazelrc` file of the third Ubuntu machine:

```
$ cat ~/.bazelrc
build --spawn_strategy=remote --genrule_strategy=remote --strategy=Javac=remote --strategy=Closure=remote --remote_executor=192.168.60.99:8980
```

### Buildfarm setup

Both got a clon of the buildfarm git repo. [The example config files](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm/tree/master/examples) were used. Just on the server I replaced `localhost` by `192.168.60.99` (master server ip).

I know that `bazel run` is not recommended. But in lack of [better alternatives that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823364/execute-bazel-buildfarm-in-a-production-ready-way-without-bazel-run), my idea is to get the documented way working first (Bazel itself doesn't mention any alternative). Since not even `bazel run` works, I think that something is wrong with my installation.

All machines use version 1.1.0, which is the latest stable one at the time of writing. It's definitely an issue with bazel-buildfarm, since the local build works fine on the Ubuntu machine.

#### Master server

```
bazel run //src/main/java/build/buildfarm:buildfarm-server $(pwd)/examples/server.config.example
```

#### Worker

```
bazel run //src/main/java/build/buildfarm:buildfarm-operationqueue-worker $(pwd)/examples/worker.config.example --distdir ~/distdir/
```

The `distdir` is a workaround for our company proxy, that manipulates files with MITM attacks. Since Bazel doesn't allow this, I downloaded the affected file for it's jdk manually:

```
[vagrant@localhost bazel-buildfarm]$ l ~/distdir/
total 188M
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant 188M Jan 17  2019 zulu11.2.3-jdk11.0.1-linux_x64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

If Bazel >= 1.0 is used , we need to specify the protocol `grpc` in `.bazelrc` like this:

```
--remote_executor=grpc://192.168.60.99:8980
```

Without the protocol, the `UNAVAILABLE: io exception` occurs. There is currently no documentation about this issue.